# Breaking out of an outer-loop from inside an inner loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops, break

I'd like to ask how I'd go about breaking out of an outer loop while inside an inner loop.

Example:

```
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        std::cout << "Say What?";
        // Insert outer-loop break statement here
    }
}
```

The above is just some pseudo code. Don't worry about logic.

Comment: Put everything in a function and `return` from the inner loop.

Comment: Use a register/int that can be checked for breaking both inner/outer loops?

Comment: @Jrok           He might not want to return from the function just yet :) ? But it's also good

Comment: Legitimate use of a goto?

Comment: @jrok Or put the inner loop in a function and return a specific value checked by the outer loop.

Comment: @hagubear: Just this loop goes into a separate function. Then returning from the function breaks out of the loop.

Comment: while(true){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    std::cout << "Say What?";
    //insert outer-loop break statement here
     break;
    }
    break;
}
Inner break will break inner loop then outer break will break outer.

Comment: Using an additional condition variable that is checked against in each nesting level of the loop is the cleanest solution here. `while (IsWorking) for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) if (Condition) {IsWorking = false; break;}`

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I'll pick @Nostromoo 's answer since I ended up using his.

Comment: @Biduleohm       Goto is usually a computer-religious no no !

Comment: @hagubear "Religious", indeed. Complectifying code just to avoid The Goto is cargo-cult programming.

Comment: @hagubear I've only used goto twice in my life but when it is useful it is really useful. Molbdnilo: exactly what I'd thought when I saw some of the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your loop in a function and **return** from it.

```
void RunMyLoop (...)
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Say What?";
            if (SomethingHappened)
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

You **could use [`goto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto).**

```
while (bKeepGoing)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Say What?";
        if (EventOccured)
        {
            goto labelEndLoop;
        }
    }
}
labelEndLoop:
//...
```

Also you could use a **boolean** to **"break" it.**

```
bool bKeepGoing = true;
while (bKeepGoing)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Say What?";
        if (EventOccured)
        {
            bKeepGoing = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to make a function out of it, this is an option:

```
bool ok = true;
while(ok){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Say What?";
        //insert outer-loop break statement here
        if(/*somthing here*/)
        {
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use a goto. But I would do this.

```
while(true){
    bool breakMe = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        std::cout << "Say What?";

        breakMe = true;
        break;
    }

    if ( breakMe )
        break;
}
```

Comment: I would not advise using goto as `goto` is always advised against until absolutely nothing else works - good programming practice

Comment: And why not simply `while (!breakMe)`, and `!breakMe && i < 2` for the condition of the `for`.  Except when ending a `case`, `break` is nothing more than a glorified `goto`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have written using a function or in C++11 better a lambda with return is the best case. But if you have to break out more nested loops different, goto can be the best.

The following pseudo code cannot be implemented with functions:

```
while (1) {
  // code
  while (1) {
    // code
    while (1) {
      // code
      if (cond1) 
        break one level;
      if (cond2) 
        break two level;
    }
  }
}
```

With goto it is possible:

```
while (1) {
  // code
  while (1) {
    // code
    while (1) {
      // code
      if (cond1) 
        goto level_a; //break one level;
      if (cond2) 
        goto level_b; // break two level;
    }
    level_a:
  }
  level_b:
}
```

Important is to be consistent. And best is to use ['algorithm'](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and *no raw loops*.

Answer (score 1):

Blacktempel has given the better way but if you don't want to use function or goto then try this:

```
int break_outer_loop = 0;
while(break_outer_loop == 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        std::cout << "Say What?";

        //insert outer-loop break statement here
        if(CONDITION FOR OUTER BREAK) {
            break_outer_loop = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't break of the outer loop directly. Try to refactor so that you could use return, or set a condition so that the while loop ends naturally.

```
bool bStop = false;

while(!bStop){
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    std::cout << "Say What?";
    bStop = true;
    break; // ends inner loop
   }
}
```

or

```
void foo(){
  while(true){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      std::cout << "Say What?";
      return;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: what does continue means here?

Comment: its not required i mean